How to Separate Text and Code in Python Strings?
I've encountered an issue in python. I have a string that contains both a message and code, and I need to separate them and pass each to different functions. An example:
text = """
Can you change sum operation to multiplication?

def process(a: int, b: int):
    print(a + b)
"""

The text and code sections can appear in any order. I've tried using regex to separate them, but it fails with other languages. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this without involving LLMS?
Thanks!
I've searched about how LLMS differentiate between code and text and found out they use Markdown formatting to separate them, like:
"See if anything is wrong with this code:"

```python
def process(a: int, b: int):
    print(a - b)
- ```

and I'm afraid I cannot follow this structure because the given input or string is not categorized like this

Please show examples of "text and code" and the corresponding expected output

The code lines in Python usually start with def, import, class and whitespace, but that is just an idea, it depends on how your Python files are formatted.

can the code have comments? please define other languages.

@WiktorStribiżew I see your point, I've tried this solution by defining some keywords and then applying regex on them. It’s somewhat acceptable, but as I mentioned, it can't be accurate as it is with python, if we bring up the matter of other languages like go, rust and more ...

@SIGHUP consider the example I mentioned in question, the expected output should be
Sentences:
Can you change sum operation to multiplication?
Code:
def process(a: int, b: int):
print(a + b)

You mean to say you want to parse many more languages with ... a single regex?

@WiktorStribiżew I didn't find another efficient way to separate them from each other.
By other languages my primarily focus is on python but if i would be able to cover other languages could be better

Need more context, but here's a little simple example of one approach to separate text and code:
text = """
Can you change sum operation to multiplication?

def process(a: int, b: int):
    print(a + b)
"""

lines = text.strip().split('\n')
code_lines = []
text_lines = []

# Define where the code starts
code_start = False
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('def '):  # Supposing as in this case line starts with function def
        code_start = True
    if code_start:
        code_lines.append(line)
    else:
        text_lines.append(line)


text_only = '\n'.join(text_lines).strip()
code_only = '\n'.join(code_lines).strip()

print(f"Text: \n{text_only}")
print(f"\nCode: \n{code_only}")

Expected output:
Text: 
Can you change sum operation to multiplication?
Code:
def process(a: int, b: int):
    print(a + b)


your code throws AttributeError. even if i correct this behavior the output is not what you claim it is. you are not taking into account that The text and code sections can appear in any order. 

You tried it adapting it in your code or you copied and pasted in a new python file? Please be more specific (also note that this was only an example of the logic you could implement/approach for what you needed)

@Yes Thanks for the answer, but it does not always work like this and the major problem is they can appear in any order.
for example : first the code part, second the sentences or text

@Callme-Milad understood, I only gave a generic example, a possible starting 'schema' for what the solution could be. Anyway, as you said, it does not always work like that. Let me know if you find a solution. (also fixed the code, there was a typo)

@folengateis sorry, there was a typo in this code, anyway as said before, this was only an idea of how this could be handled, so in case it need implementing and adapting based to the code.

@folengateis i've heard you, thanks I'll let you know if i found any solution for it.
